# Remote control a microcontroller over bluetooth from a webapp on Iphone/ipad?

Tags: iphone, web-applications, bluetooth, microcontroller

I have a microcontroller application that I will add a Bluetooth serial interface to.

Now I want to remote control the microcontroller from the Iphone (the user interface of the microcontroller application will show up in the iphone). I suppose the standard
way to to this is to develope an iphon app with Bluetooth support.

But I would like to have a web app (webpage that loads from an server on the internet over the iphones 3G conenction) that will send and receive serial data to the microcontroller through bluetooth (through JavaScript or similar). Is this possible ?

In that case I can easily add an iphone user interface to my microcontrollerbased product
with easy distribution of the web upp from a normal webserver.

Any ideas how to do this, or if it is possible?

Kind regards
TP

Answer (score 0):

If you add WiFi or Ethernet support to your microcontroller, you can serve the webapp right from the device.

This way is definitely cheaper than mobile device <--Internet--> Server Machine <--Bluetooth--> Microcontroller.

Comment: If you were to serve the web app from the device, how would the mobile device user know what IP address/URL to hit to get the web app on the device? In other words, assuming Wifi, and a DHCP-allocated IP address, how would the IP address be predictable enough to find, without the ability to make a reservation for it on the router? THanks for any guideance.